# How windows can be so cheap?

Tags: windows-10, license

I've seen [this](https://www.guru3d.com/articles-pages/urcdkey-spring-sale(up-to-86-off)-windows-10-pro-11,1.html) article in chrome recommended by Google on my phone.

Those articles are generally not completely rubbish so I'm wondering whether it's legitimate. How can I know?

$12 for Windows 10 is too low, even if it's OEM. How they can sell it so cheap?

I know this question is borderline to be off-topic, but don't have any idea where else I could ask it.

Comment: "How they can sell it so cheap?" - It is called a "gray market" license.  It's basically a license that is being resold.  If Microsoft wanted they could prevent it.

Comment: Thanks! So if a day it says the license is not valid anymore than the user can't do anything?

Comment: You can request a refund from the market place that sold you the license.  You can issue a charge back if that market place refuses to issue a refund.  You have lots of options in theory.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound! You addressed best my concern so if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ramhound explained, those are licences from grey market, originally sold in bulk and not intended to be marketed separately from a computer.

Microsoft could also invalidate them any time.

Answer (score 1):

This is an OEM license that is only good on a computer for which they were manufactured.
For example, a Dell OEM license will not work on HP.

From Microsoft's
[Licensing Logic: What's the difference between OEM, Retail and Volume Licenses?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2013/05/14/licensing-logic-whats-the-difference-between-oem-retail-and-volume-licenses/):

> OEM software is software that comes pre-installed when you purchase a new computer. So for instance when you purchase a new PC it might come with an OEM licensed copy of Windows 8.1 Pro pre-installed on it. One of the key benefits of this is that you then know that the software has been installed correctly and is working properly and if there are any issues it is the responsibility of the computer manufacturer or installer to provide support rather than Microsoft.

It's very interesting that URCDkey does not give any more information about these
licenses.

My advice: Stay away.